# oracle date to string

Tags: string, oracle, date, seconds

I have this problem: I want to convert the sysdate to string, using fillmode on month, day and hour only. However,

```
 select to_char(sysdate, 'fmmm/fmdd/yyyy fmhh12:mi:ss am') from dual
```

gives me results like

```
11/13/2013 9:45:**0** am
```

although it should be

```
11/13/2013 9:45:**00** am
```

any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: According to [Oracle Fill Mode documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements004.htm), each time you use `fm` it toggles fill mode between on and off.  So if I want to turn on fill mode for just the hour, I would put `'fmHH12:fmMI:SS AM'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `FM` format model, because `FM`, as written in the documentation:

`FM` - Used in combination with other elements to direct the suppression of leading or trailing blanks

So using `FM` will make your final string shorter, if possible.

You should remove the `FM` from your format model mask and it will work as you expect:

```
select to_char(TRUNC(sysdate), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh12:mi:ss am') from dual;
```

Output:

```
11/13/2013 12:00:00 am.
```

I've changed my answer after reading Nicholas Krasnov's comment (thanks).

More about date format models in Oracle Documentation: [Format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

**Edit**

Yes, the code I provided would return, for example, `01-01-2013`. If you want to have the month and day without leading zeroes, than you should write it like this: `fmDD-MM-YYYY fmHH:MI:SS`.

The first `fm` makes the leading zeroes be truncated. The second `fm` turns off that feature and you do get leading zeroes for the time part of the date, example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE('01-01-2013 10:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS'),
         'fmmm/dd/yyyy fmhh12:mi:ss am')
FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
1/1/2013 10:00:00 am.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but would that not produce dates like 01/01/2013 12:00:00 am? I want it wo be 1/1/2013. Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @user2986852 Yes, you are correct, I thought you wanted the leadnig zeroes for all numbers. I've edited my answer - take a look at how to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks. That was decisive. I thought i need the fillmode for every part of the datetime, but everytime i set it, I turn it on/off. I get it now, Thanks very much!